# I send my usdc from the metamask wallet to Phantom wallet usedlinea main network

Tags: phantom-wallet

I sent my Usdc from the metamask wallet used linea main network to phantom wallet used ETH recieve address and i did not get it on my phantom wallet ? can you help me to get my usdc back or is there  any chance to get it back?

Comment: this is not customer support. reach out to Phantom. downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

For assistance with this please contact Phantom support directly form your Phantom - Settings > Help & Support